# Callbacks for scheduled future in java

Tags: java, guava, java.util.concurrent

Are there any ways to add callbacks(on success, on fail) to ScheduledFuture? Seems guava with ListneableFuture doesn't provide this.

Comment: Define `fail`? A guava `ListenableFuture`  will throw an `ExecutionException` when you call `get`.

Comment: But I have ScheduledFuture, not ListenableFuture, it has no callbacks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ListenableScheduledFuture`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableScheduledFuture.html) was added in [Guava 15.0](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release15) and is now returned by the methods on [`ListenableScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningScheduledExecutorService.html).